# How to fill a row in Bootstrap grid when using mr or ml?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

I've hit the wall here.

The problem is when I try to fill the Bootstrap row by also using mr (or ml). Initially, I tried to just calculate the numbers to add up 12, so in my 3-column-layout I have a column of 5, then a column of 4, so there should be 3 left, right?

Now, it's only working until I do not try to add mr to it (between the boxes/columns) and therefore all my boxes (columns) are together. When I add mr (above 0), the 3rd column is pushed below.

I can see why, but how to get around it?

I "solved" it by only giving the 3rd column a col-xl-2 width, but then it's not filling up the space at the end of the row. Then I guessed col-lg-auto for this column will solve it, but it's even more narrow with that. I'm pretty sure manipulating column width and everything is not the answer here as it destroys the responsivity of the page, but what is it then?

Must be the same problem, but during decreasing resolution, at the point the 3rd column is pushed down anyways, the 2nd doesn't take the full space of the first row again.

My code:

```
<div class="row row-center">

<div class="col- col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-5 col-center mr-3 p-0">

    <div class="tile-first-row-text">
      A legfrissebb történések
    </div>


</div>
<div class="col- col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-center mr-3 p-0">

    <div class="tile-first-row-text">
      Tabella
    </div>


</div>
<div class="col- col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-2 col-center p-0">
  <div class="tile-first-row-text">
    Tippelde Kupa
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish. Why are you adjusting the margins at all?

Comment: I'm trying to create 'tiles' with space between them and with a shadow below them. Currently, there's no separation between the 'tiles'.

Comment: I tried the 'border-trick' as well, using the same colour of border-right as the background, but the shadow eliminates the trick.

Comment: What's the CSS for the tiles? Bootstrap columns naturally have spacing between them because the columns have padding

Answer (score 1):

Grids system are basically dividing the width into 12 parts. So adding margin to it creates additional px.

If the size is 1200px using grid system you would have divided it into 500px + 400px + 300px. Adding margin between these columns will use some of the width and the third column wont have sufficient space in that row, hence it pushes the third column to next row.

If you need space between your columns try using padding instead of margin. Hope i didn't get your question wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I was trying to use padding, but my columns have a background, therefore padding only changes the position of the text inside, doesn't create space between the columns itselves.

Comment: Open a div inside the each column and assign the background to that div. This will create space between your bg images too

Comment: You need another container just outside your present tiles but still inside your columns. Add padding to that should give you the "margins" you need.